# Como escrever a condição "if not A" de uma forma mais explícita?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como posso representar a notação `if not A` como um `if A != B` OU `if A == B`?
No caso concreto, estava trabalhando com `string` e fiz alguns testes sem efeito.
Testei `if A == None` e `if A == ""` , mas nada funcionou,
MAS
`if not A` funciona.

Então, no exemplo de reescrever `if not A` como `if A == B` OU `if A != B`, o que é B?

Comment: Que comparação precisa fazer exatamente?

Comment: Essa que é a pergunta, na verdade. 
Considerando que `A` é um string, eu preciso fazer uma condicional `if not A` para depois fazer outras funções.
A dificuldade, no momento, é representar `if not A` como um `if A == B` ou `if A != B`. A melhor solução que encontrei, por enquanto, foi `if A is None`.

Comment: Mas o que exatamente pretende verificar? Se `A` possui uma *string* não vazia? Se não é nula? Se possui um determinado valor? Ou o quê?

Comment: Tem por acaso enunciado do problema que está tentando resolver ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você faz algo como

```
if A:
    ...
```

No Python acontece o que chamamos de [*Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), que em uma tradução bastante livre seria teste de veracidade do valor.

Acontece que alguns valores são avaliados como verdadeiros ou falsos mesmo não sendo do tipo booleano. A citar aqueles que são avaliados como falso temos:

- Próprio booleano: `False`;
- Valor nulo: `None`;
- Valor zero em qualquer forma: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`;
- Sequências ou coleções vazias: `''`, `[]`, `()`, `{}`, `set()`, `range(0)`;
- Instâncias de classes definidas pelo usuário que implementam pelo menos um dos métodos `__bool__` e `__len__` e que retornam o valor zero ou `False`;

Será considerado como verdadeiro qualquer outro valor não citado.

Ou seja, a simples condição `if A` irá verificar se `A` é diferente de todas essas estruturas. Para criar uma verificação equivalente você teria que testar todas manualmente.

A verificação equivalente seria algo como:

```
if not (
    A == False
    or A is None
    or A == 0
    or A == ''
    or A == []
    or A == ()
    or A == {}
    or A == set()
    or A == range(0)
    or (hasattr(A, '__bool__') and bool(A) == False)
    or (hasattr(A, '__len__') and len(A) == 0)
):
    ...
```

Isso se eu lembrei de todas as condições.

Comment: A resposta foi bem completa. O que ficou a dúvida ainda foi como se pode escrever "if not A" de outras formas. A melhor que eu encontrei, por enquanto, foi "if A is None". 
Mas reconheço que minha pergunta foi ruim.

Comment: @AndreFerrer Mas na resposta eu te provei que `not A` **não é equivalente** a `A is None`.

Comment: Entendi agora! Muito obrigado pela ajuda. O iniciante aqui sofreu com essa lógica rs.

Answer (score 0):

O `not` irá negar algo:

```
not 1 #False
not 2 #False
not False #True
```

Então `if not A` irá simples retornar não irá se satisfazer enquanto A for `None`, `False` ou `0` (E mais alguns outros: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365341/5878).

Se quer verificar se algo é não é nulo use isto:

```
if A is not None
```

Comment: Obrigado. Acho que resolveu a pergunta.
Só pra esclarecer: escrever "if not A" é o mesmo que escrever "if A is None" OU "if A is False" OU "if A is 0"?

Comment: Eu entendi seu ponto de usar o not para validar se uma variavel é nula, porém acho que para deixar o codigo legivel, para que outras pessoas possam entender melhor, acho muito  mais elegante usar o `is`. Quando alguem bater o olhar já irá entender do que se trata.