# Python3 não reconhece o 0 como int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A questão diz que eu preciso receber entradas do usuário até que uma linha em branco seja digitada. Após o usuário terminar a entrada, eu preciso verificar nessa entrada se existem números válidos e imprimi-los no término do programa.

Seguem um exemplo de entrada dado na questão:

```
1000
abacaxi
uva
15.19
-1
+1.45
123.456-
12.34+
```

E a saída esperada:

```
Lista de Números Válidos Lidos = ['1000', '15.19', '-1', '+1.45']
```

Ou seja, palavras e números que terminam com "-" e "+" não são considerados válidos, mas os números que iniciam com "-" e "+" devem ser considerados. Até aí, sem problema.

Usei a seguinte lógica: para cada item que o usuário inseriu, eu verifico se o último caractere é inteiro. Se for, entra para uma nova lista chamada `numerosValidos`. Se não for, como é o caso das *strings* e dos números que terminam com sinal, o programa não faz nada. Segue o código:

```
def encontraValidos(lista):
    numerosValidos = []
    if len(lista) == 0:
        print("Lista de Números Válidos Lidos = {}".format(lista))
    else:
        for item in lista:
            try:
                if int(item[-1]):
                    numerosValidos.append(item)
                else:
                    pass
            except ValueError:
                pass

    return numerosValidos
```

E recebo a saída:

```
Lista de Números Válidos Lidos = ['15.19', '-1', '+1.45']
```

Entretanto, como foi dito no exemplo da questão, a entrada `"1000"` deveria aparecer nessa lista. *Debugando* o código, percebi que o `"1000"` não entra no `if int(item[-1])`, mas não consigo entender o por quê.

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Porque zero é considerado falso.

Fazer apenas `if x` executará o que chamamos de *[truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)* e nesse teste foi definido que o valor numérico zero será considerado falso¹. Assim, `if int('0')` será o mesmo que `if 0`, não executando o bloco dentro do condicional.

- [Como escrever a condição "if not A" de uma forma mais explícita?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364887/5878)

Segue a mesma ideia que a linguagem C utiliza (e talvez muitas outras), que nem possuía o tipo booleano e utilizada 0 e 1 para o serviço, sendo 0 o equivalente a falso e 1 a verdadeiro.

Aliado a isso, a sua verificação é falha. Não é suficiente apenas verificar se o último caractere é um número pois nesse caso a *string* `petunias42` ou `12uva45` seriam considerados valores numéricos válidos.

A melhor forma de tratar isso é tentando gerar uma instância de `float` a partir da entrada. Se não for um número válido será lançada a exceção `ValueError`:

```
palavras = ['1000', 'abacaxi', 'uva', '15.19', '-1', '+1.45', '123.456-', '12.34+']
numeros = []

for palavra in palavras:
    try:
        float(palavra)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    numeros.append(palavra)

print(numeros)
```

- [Como verificar se o valor de variável string é numero?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210010/5878)

---

(1): A [PEP 285](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/) que prevê a adição do tipo booleano no Python não só indica que 0 é considerado falso como sugere que o booleano seja implementado como um subtipo de `int`.

> *This PEP proposes the introduction of a new built-in type, `bool`, with two constants, `False` and `True`. The `bool` type would be a straightforward subtype (in C) of the `int` type, and the values `False` and `True` would behave like `0` and `1` in most respects (for example, `False==0` and `True==1` would be true) except repr() and str().*

Isso pode ser confirmado dentro da linguagem fazendo:

```
>>> print(isinstance(True, int))
True

>>> print(isinstance(False, int))
True

>>> print(issubclass(bool, int))
True
```